# Bootstrap responsive tables does not work inside flex context

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I need simple layout (always 100% width of browser window) with sidebar (`<aside>`) and main content (`<main>`) based on flexbox. Sidebar has constant width and main content has flexible width (rest of browser width).

Inside a main content I have big table and I want use [Responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#responsive-tables) to get horizontal scroll only on table container. But... it does not work. I got horizontal scroll for whole window.

```html
<div class="d-flex w-100">
  <aside>some sidebar content</aside>
  <main class="flex-grow-1">
    <div class="table-responsive"> <!-- problem is here! -->
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>1.Test</td>
          <td>2.Test</td>
          <td>3.Test</td>
          <!-- ... -->
          <td>21.Test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/q34p5j1u/

Answer (score 7):

Setting `min-width` to zero on my column as [Nisharg Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8798220/nisharg-shah) suggested did the trick with my Bootstrap 5 layout. I couldn't find a suitable class from Bootstrap, so I created a custom class in line with Bootstrap's convention:

```
.min-w-0 {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Here it is applied to the example from above. The table container scrolls rather than the entire layout.

```css
.min-w-0 {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex w-100 mw-100">
  <aside class="bg-info" style="height: 100px; min-width: 100px"></aside>
  <main class="bg-light flex-grow-1 min-w-0   ">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>1.Test</td>
          <td>2.Test</td>
          <td>3.Test</td>
          <td>4.Test</td>
          <td>5.Test</td>
          <td>6.Test</td>
          <td>7.Test</td>
          <td>8.Test</td>
          <td>9.Test</td>
          <td>10.Test</td>
          <td>11.Test</td>
          <td>12.Test</td>
          <td>13.Test</td>
          <td>14.Test</td>
          <td>15.Test</td>
          <td>16.Test</td>
          <td>17.Test</td>
          <td>18.Test</td>
          <td>19.Test</td>
          <td>20.Test</td>
          <td>21.Test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```